# survfit.coxph: what is the newdata argument?

Tags: survival-analysis, cox-regression

I do not understand what the newdata argument means.  Can someone explain this to me please?  I have read the documentation but honestly I just can't understand it.  When do I need to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably this is reference to a `predict` function? You need to use 'newdata' when you want to predict an outcome for a combination of predictor variables that are not in your dataset. You need to supply a list object with column names that match the RHS variables. There are many worked examples on SO if you search for `coxph` (or `survfit`) along with `predict`.